# Anaconda Data_reader package on mac?

Tags: python, anaconda

I am extremely new to programming. I have a macbook and i dont know how to install the anaconda data_reader package on my mac as it is different from the process on windows...

Comment: Are you referring to the package [pandas-datareader](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pandas-datareader) ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have pip in your machine? 
If don't, use the command Bellow:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

And then install pandas, the library that have the Data_reader.

```
pip install pandas
```

Then check this tutorial about Data_reader:

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=v66K_y3-ezY